# Python Http, getting response code from server

Tags: python, http, response

I want to get the response code from a web server, but sometime I get code 200 even if the page doesn't exist and I don't know how to deal with it.

I'm using this code:

```
def checking_url(link):
    try:  
            link = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
            response = link.code
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
            response =  e.code
    return response
```

When I'm checking a website like this one:
https://www.wykop.pl/notexistlinkkk/

It still returns code 200 even if the page doesn't exist.
Is there any solution to deal with it?

I found solution, now gonna test it with more websites
I had to use http.client.

Comment: But that url "exists" - it returns 200 OK even in browser... Try https://www.google.com/foobarblah/

Comment: On this website http.client gave me good answer, if something gonna went wrong I will write, anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You are getting response code 200, because the website you are checking has automatic redirection. In the URL you gave, even if you specify a non-existing page, it automatically redirects you to the home page, rather than returning a 404 status code. Your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2


thisCode = None 

try:
    i = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
    thisCode = i.code
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    thisCode = e.code


print thisCode
```

Comment: Did you test your code on example which one I gave?